# ASP.NET MVC: Display running time at EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to show the current time including the running second at the disabled input field in a form.

this is what i did:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Register_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @Value = DateTime.Now , @disabled="disabled"} })
```

Another way that I had tried:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Register_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("g") , @disabled="disabled"} })
```

But both do not show current time with running seconds but time in static form instead. I used the second method in another C# project to show the current time with running seconds and it worked.

What is the correct way of showing the running time at textbox.

Comment: In `another C# project` are you sure you haven't written any javascript code? is it the same kind of project?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No other Javascript code. It's a Winforms project

Comment: Winforms works differently then web application projects...  things which are shown in web pages are static unless they get changed from some client side code as javascript or they get refreshed and retrieve the new data from server..

Comment: http://www.jqchart.com/aspnetmvc/gauges/SegmentedDisplay/DigitalClock

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Good point. So I can only alter the static value by processes that happens on the client side like javascript?

Comment: Yes... correct.... you can `setTimeout` javascript function to execute some code at specific interval (let say 1 second), and the code should display the current time to some HTML section (label in your case.).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using @Html.EditorFor, you can use @Html.TextBox()

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zbTXkV

Comment: thanks for the idea but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I modified above fiddle with the javascript code to show the running timer. https://dotnetfiddle.net/pBT7HL

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya actually getValidTime() function is not used right? I removed var currentTime = getValidTime();  It still works in your fiddle

Comment: Bc it seems like a recursion with 1 sec interval on Date() function which is the current datetime

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some javascript to make the clock work.

Try out the following code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Test, new { @id = "txtBox", @disabled = "disabled" })

@section scripts {

<script>

    var textBox = document.getElementById('txtBox');

    function time() {
        var d = new Date();
        var s = d.getSeconds();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var h = d.getHours();
        textBox.value =
            ("0" + h).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).substr(-2);
    }

    setInterval(time, 1000);

</script>
}
```